# Display TXT file in webpage - client side/javascript console

Tags: javascript, html

There's a webpage I'm visiting, and I want to change its contents using my Javascript console. In place of the current contents, i want to put a txt file from my computer.

So far, I've pin pointed the element using its class name, and I've managed to change the contents using the innerHTML property. However, attempting to load the txt file is giving me an error: "The address wasn't understood, Firefox doesn't know how to open..."

my code:

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("share-mod-left");
e[0].innerHTML = "hello world"; //works
e[0].innerHTML = '<iframe src="C:\Users\MyAcc\Documents\test.txt"></iframe>'; //won't open
```

Edit:
This didn't solve my problem, but I know the backslashes in the path were being removed. I doubled them so that javascript would read it correctly `src="C:\\Users\\MyAcc\\Documents\\test.txt"`

Solution:
I had to upload the file to a server, and read it from there. (there were quite a few services that offered txt uploading).

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/?redirect_from_locale=ko Perhaps this link would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file://` scheme is required in your path.

Comment: It's no longer displaying the error, but neither is it displaying the txt file.

Comment: You need to ensure that you're running it from a page using the ```file://``` protocol. For obvious security reasons you can't display local files in pages fetched by the ```http://``` scheme.

Comment: Fair point about the security reasons. I had hoped that the browser could distinguish between code I created vs the code on the web page, but I didn't really have a basis for that. Unfortunately the page is external (http)

Comment: From what you're saying, this might be salvageable if I find a server that will upload the txt file and link it